# Delete channel on reaction // Ticket Bot discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im trying to make a ticket bot, and this is currently what i have. Now that i can make the bot create a channel after detecting a reaction, i need to be able to make it close the ticket on another reaction, as well as other features iw ant to add. But this reaction is in the channel created so i dont know how to get that channel id created. Someone suggested me to use cogs, but  have no idea where to start.

````
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = payload.channel_id
    if channel == 862711339298455563:
        guildid = payload.guild_id
        guild = client.get_guild(guildid)
        channel = guild.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
        message = channel.get_partial_message(payload.message_id)
        emoji = '️'
        member = payload.member
        

        payloaduserid = payload.user_id
        clientuserid = client.user.id   
        if payloaduserid != clientuserid: 
            await message.remove_reaction(emoji, member)
            category = client.get_channel(861003967000215583)
            channel1 = await guild.create_text_channel(f'ticket {payload.user_id}', category = category )

            ticketembed = discord.Embed(
                title = f'Ticket - {payload.user_id}',
                description = '- If you want to tag the admins please react with :telephone: \n - To report this message please react with   :warning: \n - To close the ticket react this mesaage with   :x:  ',
                color = discord.Color.red())
            ticketembed.set_footer(text = 'All of the conversation will be held in the archives, eventhought a moderator can delete a message in this channel, a copy of it will be held in a location where only the owner can access.')



            user = client.get_user(payload.user_id)
            await channel1.set_permissions(target=user, read_messages=True , send_messages=True)
            
            ticketembed1 = await channel1.send(embed= ticketembed)

            await ticketembed1.add_reaction('☎️')
            await ticketembed1.add_reaction('⚠️')
            await ticketembed1.add_reaction('❌') 
            await channel1.send(f'{user.mention}', delete_after = 0.1) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

One method is checking the channel name format. sometimes getting the channel from cache is not an option so we might need to fetch it.

```py
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    # if channel is not in cache then fetch is using a API request
    if not channel:
        channel = await client.fetch_channel(channel_id)
    # The user is the owner of the ticket since it is his id
    if channel.name == f"ticket {payload.user_id}":
        emoji = payload.emoji.name

        # delete 
        if emoji == "❌":
            await channel.delete()
```

It is better to save channel id and then use it since channel name can be changed. You can get the id like this.

```py
channel1 = await guild.create_text_channel(f'ticket {payload.user_id}', category = category )
print(channel1.id)
```

Comment: First of all i need to define channel another time but as a channel name, so client.get_channel(payload.channel_id). And when i try that it doesnt seem like it is working

Comment: `print(channel.name)` to see if it is there, using `get_channel` will use cache and it might not be there therefore you need to use `fetch_channel`. I edited the code above